# Elasticsearch hadoop configure bulk batch size

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop, elasticsearch-spark

I read through possibly Stackoverflow that es-hadoop / es-spark projects use bulk indexing. If it does is the default batchsize is as per BulkProcessor(5Mb). Is there any configuration to change this.

I am using `JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(dataset,index)` in my code and I want to know what are the available configurations available to tune the performance. Is this related to partitioning of dataset also.

Answer (score 0):

Found settings on their configuration page

```
es.batch.size.bytes (default 1mb)
```

Size (in bytes) for batch writes using Elasticsearch bulk API. Note the bulk size is allocated per task instance. Always multiply by the number of tasks within a Hadoop job to get the total bulk size at runtime hitting Elasticsearch.

```
es.batch.size.entries (default 1000)
```

Size (in entries) for batch writes using Elasticsearch bulk API - (0 disables it). Companion to es.batch.size.bytes, once one matches, the batch update is executed. Similar to the size, this setting is per task instance; it gets multiplied at runtime by the total number of Hadoop tasks running.